# Error: Assembly uses System.Web.Mvc, which has a higher version that referenced assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have created a library, Foo, which is meant to be included in ASP.NET MVC projects. It references MVC 5.2.3.0. I created a demo project, using the same version of MVC, and everything works great.

Now, I want to use Foo in another project, a real project "Bar", but it's using MVC 5.2.2.0.

When I do this (by adding a reference to Foo.dll), I get an error:

`Error    71  Assembly 'Foo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'`

I've been messing with the binding redirects in Bar's web.config and Foo's app.config, but nothing seems to help. Is there anything I can do to make this work? For MVC specifically, but for any situation like this in general.

For the sake of this question, assume I can't upgrade "Bar" to the newer version of MVC, but I have full control to edit the Foo project.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't upgrade Bar, then downgrade Foo to 5.2.2.0. The only reason for this error is the difference in the version of the `System.Web.Mvc`